# Current excel formula gives nothing but ####### (and it's not the column width)

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have the following formula:

```
=NETWORKDAYS(EOMONTH(BJ6, 0) + 1, EOMONTH(BJ6, 0))
```

which results in just "##########" forever (it's not a column width thing). I'm simply trying to get the number of working days from cell BJ6 which is a custom format "MMM-YY". BJ6 is actually created by another formula and I'm thinking that may be the issue.

Any ideas?

Comment: Your start date is after your end date.  you need to switch the criteria

Comment: May I know what is in cell BJ6?

Comment: BJ6 = "Jan-24". I also switched the criteria and the result comes out to 2. The new formula is =NETWORKDAYS(EOMONTH(BJ6, 0), EOMONTH(BJ6, 0) + 1).

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out. To calculate the number of working days for each month...

```
=NETWORKDAYS(EOMONTH(BJ6, -1) + 1, EOMONTH(BJ6, 0))
```